# How to make an "intersect" query on Relationships in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a Model "Pro" which has a table like "langs_pro". The langs table contains the shorthand for a language (like, fr, en, es, etc.).

In a query, I want to give an array of languages (let's say hu, it, fr) and check if at least one value is equal in both arrays.

However, how can I achieve that without retrieving each model manually? Is there an easier way, like with a MySQL query?

Comment: "and check if at least one value is equal in both arrays.". Which "both arrays"? I cant tell what you're trying to do. Maybe accompany the question with a small table example

Answer (score 0):

you can use eager loading and whereHas query:

```
Pro::with([
    "lang" => function($query) { $query->whereIn("language", ["it", "fr"]); }
])->whereHas("lang", function($query){
    $query->where("col", "value");
})->get();
```

Note: "lang" is the name of relationship